# Como ignorar a altura de um elemento dentro de uma caixa com altura automática em CSS?

Tags: html, css

Sou iniciante em HTML e CSS e estou fazendo um trabalho de tema livre para o meu curso, mas acabei empacando em um ponto.
Tenho o seguinte código em um trecho do meu HTML:

```
<section id=#first>
    <h1> Recomendações da semana </h1>
    <ul>
    <a href="http://myanimelist.net/anime/10793/Guilty_Crown" target="_blank">
        <li><img src="img/gc.png"/><h2>Guilty Crown</h2></li>
    </a>
    <a href="http://myanimelist.net/anime/11757/Sword_Art_Online" target="_blank">
        <li><img src="img/sao.png"/><h2>Item 1</h2></li>
    </a>
    <a href="http://myanimelist.net/anime/12189/Hyouka" target="_blank">
        <li><img src="img/hyouka.png"/><h2>Hyouka</h2></li>
    </a>
    <a href="http://myanimelist.net/anime/11887/Kokoro_Connect" target="_blank">
        <li><img src="img/kkr_con.png"/><h2>Kokoro Connect</h2></li>
    </a>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Para a section, a altura é automática (`height: auto;`), assim como para o `li`. O que eu quero é que a altura desses containers seja igual à altura da imagem, uma vez que o `h2` fica por cima dela. Porém, conforme a tela é redimensionada, uma faixa branca vai sendo adicionada ao container (creio que seja a altura+padding do `h2`).

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para ignorar a altura do `h2`, restando apenas a altura da imagem no container.

Segue o código usado no CSS:

```
#first{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1440px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#first:after{
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
section h2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: white;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 47px;
}
section ul{
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
section ul a li{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 306px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
}
section ul a li img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

O resultado final com a tela cheia:
[image: Note que mesmo na resolução máxima há uma linha branca abaixo do h2]

Conforme a tela é redimensionada e fica menor:
[image: Uma faixa branca é adicionada abaixo da imagem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto está a acontecer porque estás a usar `position:relative;` no teu título `h2`.

isto pode ser resolvido movendo o atributo `position:relative;` para a tua `li` e dando um `position:absolute;` ao teu `h2` em vez de `relative` para poderes alcançar o estilo pretentido:

```
li {position:relative;}
h2 {position:absolute; bottom:0;}
```

No entanto eu reparei em vários erros de marcação no teu código HTML, e a estrutura do teu CSS também pode ser melhorada, aqui está o código com todos os erros corrigidos e melhorado:

Podes também ver um exemplo online aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/xv2h4utc/

```
<section id="first">
    <h1> Recomendações da semana </h1>
        <ul>
            <li class="reco-li">
                <a href="http://myanimelist.net/anime/10793/Guilty_Crown" target="_blank">
                <img src="img/gc.png"/><h2>Guilty Crown</h2>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="reco-li">
                <a href="http://myanimelist.net/anime/11757/Sword_Art_Online" target="_blank">
                <img src="img/sao.png"/><h2>Item 1</h2>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="reco-li">
                <a href="http://myanimelist.net/anime/12189/Hyouka" target="_blank">
                <img src="img/hyouka.png"/><h2>Hyouka</h2>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="reco-li">
                <a href="http://myanimelist.net/anime/11887/Kokoro_Connect" target="_blank">
                <img src="img/kkr_con.png"/><h2>Kokoro Connect</h2>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</section>
```

```
.reco-li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    max-height: 306px;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#first{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.reco-li h2{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: white;
    font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#first ul{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: table-cell; /* isto é uma correcção para poder usar a border abaixo correctamente */
    border: 5px solid #000;
}

.reco-li img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

A class `#first:after` não está aqui a fazer nada, mas se por alguma razão precises de usar `clear:both;` cria uma class especialmente para esta propriedade e usa-o da seguinte maneira:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

```
.clear {clear:both;}
```

Comment: Realmente, resolveu o problema.  Quanto à organização das marcações que você passou, também resolveu outro problema que surgiu após implementar as alterações. Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @Frost :) provavelmente o outro problema deverá ter sido por causa disto: `<section id=#first>` no teu código HTML que eu modifiquei e consertei para `<section id="first">` na minha resposta. Existiam outros erros também, mas este era o mais relevante. Este tipo de erros de marcação podem fazer com o código deixe de funcionar ou que algum estilo CSS não seja implementado correctamente. Happy Coding =)